# Django Admin - How can i add more than one related object?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

For example i have this code

```
app/models.py
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Question(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

At first, I can add in Django Admin Poll, next i can add some question and answers to question, but i can do it only after creating poll and i can add only one question and answers to it at first time. How i can do it in one page while creating or updating `Poll` and add more than one question+answers?

Comment: If you want all 3 in one you are looking for django nested inlines

Comment: @jamylak but all django nested inlines works with django 1.6 only ...